# PHP doesn't catch POST data

Tags: php

I have a dynamic form for upload a image or a YouTube video to slideshow. But when i click send, the server doesn't catch the data. I can see in my browsers network panel that I send a post request to the server that is populated with the parameters. But when the server gets the request the $_POST array is empty.

The code worked before but I haven't been working on for like a half year but it worked just a few weeks ago. Only thing I have been doing is working on another website and change some PHP settings at my webhotel but I can't find any that would stop POST requests.

I removed all the input fields since SO wouldn't let me post so much code.

```
<form id="slideForm" action="php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset id="media">
        <legend>Load upp new slide </legend>
    <label for="mediaType">Media type</label>
    <select name="mediaType" id="mediaType">
        <option value="empty" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="image">Image (jpeg, jpg, png)</option>
        <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
    </select>

    <div id="local"> <!-- Only if image is selected -->
        <label for="localImageLocal">Local file</label>
        <input type="radio" name="localImage" id="localImageLocal" value="local" />
        <label for="lovalImageUrl">Internet image</label>
        <input type="radio" name="localImage" id="localImageUrl" value="url" />
    </div>

    <div id="image">
        <div id="imageFileDiv">
            <label for="imageFile">Upload image (jpeg, jpg, png)</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4000000" />
            <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="urlImageDiv">
            <label for="urlImage">Url to image</label>
            <input type="url" name="urlImage" id="urlImage">
            <br />
            <div id="imageName">
                <label for="urlImageName">Name the image</label>
                <input type="text" name="urlImageName" id="urlImageName" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="youtube">
        <label for="youtubeUrl">Url to video </label>
        <input type=url name="youtubeUrl" id="youtubeUrl" checked />
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="settingsField">
        <div id="settings">
        <div id="effects">
            <h2>Effects</h2>
            <label for="effectNone">None</label>
            <input type="radio"     name="effect[]" id="effectNone"     value="none" checked />
            <label for="effectBlink">Blink</label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="effect[]" id="effectBlink"    value="blink"/>
            <label for="effectHorn">Horn</label>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="effect[]" id="effectHorn"     value="horn"/>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div id="videoSettings">
            <!--<label for="playToEnd"> Play to end off video </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="playToEnd" id="playToEnd" value="playToEnd"> -->
            <span> Video will allways run to the end </span>
        </div>

        <div id="duration">
            <label for="duration" >Image duration: </label>
            <span id="durationLabel">10</span>
            <input type="range" name="duration" id="durationRange" min="1" value="10" max="180" step="1" />
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="priority">
            <label for="priority">Priority</label>
            <input type="number" name="priority" id="priority" min="0" value="0"/>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="startSettings">
            <label for="startNow"> Start now </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="startNow" id="startNow" value="true" checked/>

            <div id="timeAndDate">

                <label for="startDate">Start date</label>
                <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" value="2015-01-01" />
                <label for="startTime">Start time</label>
                <input type="text" name="startTime" id="startTime" value="00:00:00" />

                <br />

                <label for="endDate">End date</label>
                <input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" value="2015-01-02" />
                <label for="endTime">End time</label>
                <input type="text" name="endText" id="endTime" value="24:00:00" />
            </div>

        </div><!-- END startSettings -->
    </div><!-- END settings -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="ADD"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Booth the $_POST and $_REQUEST is empty

```
require_once("config.php");
var_dump($_REQUEST);
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])){
    exit("No data");
}
```

My settings:
[image: PHP settings]

[image: PHP module settings]

Comment: inputs are dynamic inside form?

Comment: What input tags and values are you using? Can you update the exact code?

Comment: Use `$_FILES`(in case of images). check `var_dump($_FILES)` in your code. Also `action="php/upload.php"` check this path is correct or not. because it must be a problem that your form not able to find that page

Comment: Do your fields has name?

Comment: could you post your submit button ?? `html` 

does dynamically appended input are binds on document ...??

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya, @santosh The form is dynamic in the way that I have JS that changes the CSS with `display: none` or `display visible` depending on what fields I have filled. The PHP will check all the names and take out those who are filled.